# Can someone listen GSM calls with RTL-SDR dongle if A5/1 cryptography is successfully cracked?

Tags: gsm

Can an attacker listen GSM calls in clear audio form (real time) using RTL-SDR dongle if he/she has powerful-enough hardware to crack the A5/1 crypto scheme in countries where no more secure cryptography is used by mobile operators for encrypting the conversations?

How easy this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes - but it needs work.

Some background: If - as you assume - A5/1 is cracked, than the attack scenario is the same as using no encryption at all.  [Karsten Nohl showed in 2010](https://srlabs.de/decrypting_gsm/) that if you have the key Kc, you can decode a GSM phone call.

Open Points or things that must be done:

1. Currently only the downlink channel was attacked (this is the communication from the base station to the phone).  This signal can be traced in the whole cell.  Uplink traffic (communication from the phone to the cell) is somewhat harder to trace (e.g. no synchronization logical channel like the FCCH in the downlink, weak signal).
2. Base stations are allowed to use channel hopping, i.e. the traffic is transmitted over multiple physical frequencies.  Because it is IMHO not possible to switch the frequency of the RTL SDR in that short period of time, you need typically more than one device to listen to all physical frequencies at once.  So, if the cell has three hopping channels, you need six devices: three for downlink and three for uplink.
3. Synchronization of these devices must be done: on the 'analog' side the frequency offset (evaluation of the FCCH) and on the digital the synchronizations of the frames of different frequencies.  IMHO there is currently no free and open source software available handling these kind of things.
4. If you want decoding in real time, there is also some work needed.  Software like [airprobe](https://svn.berlin.ccc.de/projects/airprobe/) can be used for tracing calls, but it's used more like a batch job (collecting data and afterwards processing).

(Please note that the answer is only about GSM. In 3G (UMTS) or 4G (LTE) it's completely different.)

Answer (score 0):

Documents leaked by Ed Snowden reveal that the NSA has the capability to listen to GSM calls.

http://www.washingtonpost.com/business/technology/by-cracking-cellphone-code-nsa-has-capacity-for-decoding-private-conversations/2013/12/13/e119b598-612f-11e3-bf45-61f69f54fc5f_story.html

This shouldn't be surprising.  There's been a known time-memory tradeoff to speed cracking of of A5/1 for quite a while, and a few efforts to publicly create the needed lookup tables.  Creating the rainbow tables takes a lot of initial computational effort, but once you've created them, it's considerably easier to break A5/1.

Probably an easier attack would be to simply do a MITM attack and just turn off the encryption.

Easiness level?  It seems to be ad about the level of a single dedicated, not well funded attacker, but beyond Joe-Sixpack armed with Google.  (For instance, in the 90s even Joe Sixpack could buy a bearcat scanner and listen to analog cell phone calls.)